# Html table misaligned under Windows using any browser (Firefox, Chrome and IE), but working fine under Linux

Tags: html, css

An image is worth 1024 words, right? so I tried to post some images but I don't have enough reputation, so it's going to be a little more difficult to describe with words, but I hope that someone can help me.

The thing is that I have a table that shows misaligned only under Windows, no matter if using IE8, Firefox or Chrome. Under Linux the table shows fine in Firefox and Chrome. So, I used the IE8's development tools and find out that the margins are set to 0, and if I disable the margins the table shows almost fine (top margin gets some value) but the right margin now shows aligned. Then if I apply margins again the top margin gets set to 0 and the right margin stays fine, and the table shows as it is meant to.

The weirdest part of all is that it works fine under Windows and Linux for other clients of the application, but for one particular client it just does not. The code does not depend on the client.

Edited:

The code is not something I'm writing, It's already written, like ages ago, and I have to fix some parts. It's a very large and complex application, with sensible data, so I have to obscure some of the code and the images, sorry for that, but now I've isolated the problem.

You can download the code and test it locally. You'll find out that the table shows misplaced only under Windows in any browser.

In order for you to understand what exactly the issue is, I'm posting 2 links. One of them is a code that shows fine, the other one has the issue. Both of them should work fine since it's the same application. I hope this is more clarifying. Look at the misaligned table, go to the development tools in IE and watch the margin values, then watch what happens when the margins are disabled and enabled again.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bxz1pQbINNQKbDRHYXFxUFk1aFU/edit

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bxz1pQbINNQKYi1icEM4dFlGeW8

I had to remove the previous link to the images because I can upload only 2 links due to my privileges, but now you have the code, so it wasn't going to be that useful anyway. Maybe you might want to see the pics:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/uvzkR#3]

Comment: Please post your code and/or a jsFiddle (jsfiddle.net)

Comment: You can post links to your image that we can see, and if we're feeling generous someone with enough rep can edit your post and embed them.

Comment: You shouldn't be [using tables](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/) for that page in the first place.

Comment: My Spanish is exceptionally poor, but the debugger appears to be reporting that you are in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). Don't use quirks mode.

Comment: Quentin, I know my original question wasn't well made, I even earned a downvote, but I had a hard time to put it in words.

Anyway, if the problem was my IE then Chrome and Firefox wouldn't fail, rigth? but they do, and what about the clients of the application, rigth? So, it's not the quirks mode of IE. and I can't go to my boss and original developers in the US and tell'em that they shouldn't have written html tables because it's stupid, don't you think?

Comment: You might want to consider putting your html code through a validator. http://validator.w3.org/ I found a few errors which might need addressing. Good luck!

Comment: @Jack — IE is not the only browser to implement quirks mode.

Comment: @Jack — If you can't call out out of date, inefficient, hard to maintain, and just plain bad coding practises in your organisation then you have a cultural problem rather then a technical one. :(

Comment: Quentin, maybe you're right, but you aren't giving me any viable solution, nor good advice, nor even a clue of what's going on, or I should say going wrong, with the code... thanks anyway for your good intentions.

Comment: Thanks very much Ben, I'm going to check that.

Comment: @Jack — I gave as much advice as was possible from the screenshot you posted. Not using code that follows the conventions of 1997 is good advice. Quirks mode causes all sorts of problems, standard debugging is "Is something wrong? Yes. Are you in Quirks mode? Yes. Stop, switch to standards mode. Retest". Until you get out of Quirks mode it simply isn't worth the effort to investigate further (not that investigating further was possible based on the screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Well... The problem was nothing else that the dots in some ip numbers!

It was difficult to spot because not all data had ip numbers.

The solution could be to change xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx for xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx or something like that.

I hope it's useful for someone else.